# Demo reel show n tell

Tags: demo-reel, design, mix

Some I'd you may know me or some of my team personally, and I have posted quite a bit. But am often busy with work and not as "social" as would like to be. So I wanted to share our project reel from 2011. It's great to have and be a part of this community!

http://giftofsound.ca/en/reel.html

Look forward to your comments.

-Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matt,

Very cool reel! Really liked the tense atmospheric horror-styled sound design in certain parts.

My reel is not as concise and coherent as yours, but I'll throw my hat in the ring here:
http://sethnorman.com/

Thanks,
Seth

Comment: Thanks Seth. I watched the clips on your site. Very cool stuff indeed! Thanks for your comments and sharing your reel as well! Rock on man